# MySql select query distinct digit except zero

Tags: mysql

I have a table column like this::

```
         SendID
           0
           0
           0
           0
           0
          22
          22
          22
          33
          33
```

I wants the following result:

```
               SendID
                 0
                 0
                 0
                 0
                 0
                22
                33
```

Actually I want select all the zeros and distinct digit except 0.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/)

Comment: select distinct SendID from message where SendID <>0

Comment: @Rounak You forgot the `WHERE` keyword ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using [`UNION`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/union.html), you can combine a query that selects all of the zeroes with another `DISTINCT` one that selects everything else only once:

```
  SELECT          SendID FROM mytable WHERE SendID =  0
UNION ALL
  SELECT DISTINCT SendID FROM mytable WHERE SendID <> 0
```